# Twisted: ConnectionPool Re-Connects to Different Database

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I have ConnPool class which inherited from twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool class.

```
class ConnPool(ConnectionPool):
    def __init__(self):  
        ConnectionPool.__init__(self, 'MySQLdb', address, user,pass, MYSQL_DB, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True, cp_min=1, cp_max=MAX_CONNECTION, cp_reconnect=True)
```

It works fine with one database connection. But, i want it to connect another database when the connection is lost.

Detection of loss of connection is done, but i could not manage ConnPool class to connect another database in this situation.

I tried to reinitialize ConnectionPool class when the specific event occurs, but it did not work.

Any idea/solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `ConnectionPool.connect`, is it there you should point you
attention. `adbapi` does not provide the logic for such situation, it is
not difficult to implement something very silly but it is the behavior
that require more attention. For example how `ConnectionPool` react when
all the servers are down?

Here just a dumb implementation:

```
class ArgumentPool:

    def __init__(self, connargs, connkw):
        assert len(connargs) == len(connkw)
        self.connargs = connargs
        self.connkw = connkw

    def next(self):
        while 1:
            for args, kwds in zip(self.connargs, self.connkw.values()):
                yield args, kwds


class RRConnectionPool(adbapi.ConnectionPool):

    def __init__(self, dbapiName, ap):
        adbapi.ConnectionPool.__init__(self, dbapiName)
        self.ap = ap

    def connection(self):
        # ...
        args, kwds = self.ap.next()
        conn = self.dbapi.connect(*args, **kwds)
        # ...
```